# rails 3.2 omniauth ssl windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ssl, omniauth

Apologies if this has been answered already, but I'm going through the posts here and can't find something that works.

I've got Devise working with rails for authentication, and I'm trying to integrate OmniAuth for facebook.  I'm getting the SSL error that has been posted about in the past.

My error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I've been through the solutions for windows and none seem to work.  I'm just trying to get this working in dev on a windows machine, so I'm willing to take unsecure shortcuts to get it up and running and then figure out what's necessary in production later on.

I'm using:

```
rails 3.2.2
warden 1.1.1
devise 2.0.4
faraday 0.7.6
oauth2 0.5.2
omniauth 1.0.3
omniauth-oauth2 1.0.0
omniauth-facebook 1.2.0
```

I've tried a couple different things in omniauth.rb:

omniauth.rb:

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join('lib/assets/cacert.pem').to_s}}}
    #provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
    end
```

The second option (commented) is supposed to suppress ssl cert checking entirely, as far as I understand it.  But that doesn't work - same error.  With the first option, I downloaded the appropriate file and put it in by lib/assets directory, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Has something changed recently with this?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way to do it is here:
https://gist.github.com/867550

Answer (score 0):

Try following the instructions given in this link:
http://jimneath.org/2011/10/19/ruby-ssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

And you have to make this minor change in `fix_ssl.rb` at the end:

```
self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
```

I hope this helps.